# Conversion of Scala map containing Boolean to Java map containing java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, scala, interop

I'd like to convert a scala map with a Boolean value to a java map with a java.lang.Boolean value (for interoperability).

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val a = Map[Int, Boolean]( (1, true), (2, false) )
val b : java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = a
```

fails with:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.Boolean]
required: java.util.Map[Int,java.lang.Boolean]
val b : java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = a
```

The JavaConversions implicit conversions work happily with containers parameterized on the same types, but don't know about the conversion between Boolean & java.lang.Boolean.

Can I use the JavaConversions magic to do this conversion, or is there a concise syntax for doing the conversion without using the implicit conversions in that package?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `JavaConversions` will convert the Scala Map to a `java.util.Map`, and Scala implicitly converts `scala.Boolean` to `java.lang.Boolean`, Scala won't perform two implicit conversions to get the type you want.

[`Boolean`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Boolean%24) provides a `box` method for explicit conversion.

```
val b: java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = a.mapValues(Boolean.box)
```

If you're doing this frequently in your code, you can define your own implicit conversion for all `Map[T, Boolean]`.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

implicit def boolMap2Java[T](m: Map[T, Boolean]): 
  java.util.Map[T, java.lang.Boolean] = m.mapValues(Boolean.box)

val b: java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = a
```

Comment: Thanks. Will Scala ever chain two implicit conversions?

Comment: According to [Programming in Scala](http://amzn.com/0981531644), no.  "One-at-a-time Rule: Only one implicit is tried."

Answer (score 12):

`scala.collection.JavaConversions` isn't going to help you with the `scala.Boolean` to `java.lang.Boolean` problem. The following will work, though, using the `boolean2Boolean` method from [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/Predef%24.html):

```
val a = Map[Int, Boolean](1 -> true, 2 -> false)
val b: java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = a.mapValues(boolean2Boolean)
```

Or you can use Java's `Boolean(boolean value)` constructor:

```
val a = Map[Int, Boolean](1 -> true, 2 -> false)
val b: java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = 
         a.mapValues(new java.lang.Boolean(_))
```

Or you can just declare the first map to use the Java reference type:

```
val a = Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean](1 -> true, 2 -> false)
val b: java.util.Map[Int, java.lang.Boolean] = a
```

Comment: You're missing `asJava` in both cases to convert the Map.

Comment: @Joachim: You only need `asJava` if you're using `JavaConverters`. The question and my answer use the `JavaConversions` object, which does the conversion implicitly.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about JavaConversions, thanks. You typo'd in your comment just above this but found the name in the answer.