# How to parse None received for a Map value together with a function call?

Tags: scala, collections, pattern-matching

Originally I wrote a method to parse boolean values of various metrics and was interested only in getting `true` and `false`. So I used `fold` to work with non-empty option's value.

```
    def parseMetrics(metricKeys: Seq[String], metricsMap: mutable.Map[String, lang.Boolean],
                   transactionValue: String): List[String] = {
    metricKeys.map { metricKey =>
      metricsMap.get(metricKey).fold(StringUtils.EMPTY) { metricValue =>
        if (metricValue) "Y" else "N"
      }
    }.toList
  }
```

Now I decided to change the logic to use the case when metric value is null and `metricsMap.get(metricKey)` returns None

// pseudo-code

```
val maybeBoolean = metricsMap.get(metricKey)
case Some(maybeBoolean) - evaluate metricValue to "Y" or "N" as before
case None && isValidTransaction(transactionValue) then metricValue = "V"
```

But I'm probably missing something and pattern matching isn't working in this case. The function `isValidTransaction(transactionValue)` can not get resolved. And my attempt to match None and the function call fails.

How should I fix the logic to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
def parseMetrics(metricKeys: Seq[String], metricsMap: Map[String, Boolean], transactionValue: String): List[String] = {
  metricKeys.map(metricsMap.get).map {
    case Some(true) => "Y"
    case Some(false) => "N"
    case None if isValidTransaction(transactionValue) => "V"
    case None => "unknown"
  }.toList
}
```

Comment: As a possible alternative, since you are handling booleans, you may consider defining a case for every possible outcome as part of the pattern match instead of having a nested `if`: `case Some(true) => "Y"; case Some(false) => "F"` etc.

Comment: Something along these lines: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/43Vs1joZRHu0HudE9h8aqA/10

Comment: Thanks for incorporating my suggestion in your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you. There is one problem with your solution. Since I'm using a  `mutable.Map[String, lang.Boolean]`, I'm getting a `Type mismatch: expected Option[Boolean] => NotInferedB, actual: String` when trying to pattern-match

Comment: @samba I cannot seem to reproduce that. Changing to `metricsMap: mutable.Map[String, Boolean]` and then passing in something like `mutable.Map("1" -> true, "2" -> false)` seems to work fine on my machine.

Comment: Note the `lang.Boolean`

Comment: @samba Ah I see, you are using java booleans. Try `case Some(v) => if (v) "Y" else "Z"`. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638492/conversion-of-scala-map-containing-boolean-to-java-map-containing-java-lang-bool